# FeedForward Neural Network on ThingSpeak Channel

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, neural-network, iot, matlab-deployment

I am doing a project and I have code of a few lines in MATLAB which is trained and tested on a given data set with 70-30 % distribution. This is the code:

```
clc
clear all
close all
x=xlsread('Training');
y=xlsread('Output');
t=xlsread('Test');
x=x';
y=y';
t=t';
net=feedforwardnet(50);
net.layers{1},transferFCN='gaussian';
net.layers{2},transferFCN='hyperbolic tan';
view(net);
net=train(net,x,y)
a=sim(net,t)
```

Now My live data is coming in a ThingSpeak channel (There are total 6 fields in the channel ) and I want to analyze that data through this code and take decisions. What changes I should make to run it in ThingSpeak as a MATLAB Analysis? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your lines:

```
x=xlsread('Training');
y=xlsread('Output');
t=xlsread('Test');
```

will now come from a ThingSpeak channel. Here's an example of thingSpeakRead in MATLAB:

```
data = thingSpeakRead(12397,'Fields',[1,4],NumPoints=3,OutputFormat='TimeTable')
```

Here's the doc for [thingSpeakRead](https://www.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/thingspeakread.html).